# Final code problem in finding the nearest neighbour

Tags: python, for-loop, spyder, nearest-neighbor

I need help for this code in finding the nearest neighbor distance between point locations. I think the problem is that instead of adding 'nearestdistance' to 'Sumdistance' only if it is smaller than the previous 'newdistance' it adds the nearest distance no matter what. Though I might be wrong. Code shown below:

```
q = loadPoints(f)

n = 1416
Sumdistance = 0

for i in q:
    iID = int(i.getID())
    x1 = float(i.getX())
    y1 = float(i.getY())
    nearestdistance = 999999999999999999999999999
    for j in range(0, n):
        if j != iID:
            jID = (q[j].getID())
            x2 = float(q[j].getX())
            y2 = float(q[j].getY())
            dx = x1 - x2
            dy = y1 - y2
            newdistance = math.sqrt(math.pow(dx,2) + (math.pow(dy,2)))
                                
            if newdistance < nearestdistance:
                nearestdistance = newdistance
                else nearestdistance = 
                
    Sumdistance = Sumdistance + nearestdistance
    
area = 10000000000
Do = Sumdistance/n
De = 0.5/(math.sqrt(n/area))
ANN = Do/De
print(ANN)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct - you should always add `nearestdistance` to `Sumdistance` after iterating the neighbors.

```
for i in q:
    ......
    for j in range(0, n):
        if j != iID:
            ........
                                
            if newdistance < nearestdistance:
                nearestdistance = newdistance
                
    Sumdistance += nearestdistance
```

Note that the final sum will include reverse neighbors, ie `a -> b` and `b -> a`